# SSH - Key based authentication fails after password prompt

Tags: ssh, openssh, rsa

I'm running into SSH errors when connecting to a server as a particular user when using key based authentication with an associated password on the key.

This is on an IBM i system.

I've added the public key to the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file on the server for that user. Their home directory, along with the `~/.ssh` directory and the `/.ssh/authorized_keys` file do not have write permissions for anyone other than the owner.  And the owner is properly set for all of them.  Interesting enough, if I move those same keys to another user, the password is accepted.  Alternatively, if I use a key pair which works for a different user for the user JAV, I get the same behavior.  So it seems there is something about the user "JAV" on the server-side which is at the root of this.

What's odd is that the connection attempt doesn't fail until after the user is prompted for a password.  Everything I can find points to file permissions being inaccurate, but I've matched the permissions for relevant files between the user which works and the user which doesn't - and their identical.

JAV is the user which doesn't work.

Permissions for `/home/JAV` and `.ssh`:

```
bash-4.4$ pwd
/home/JAV
bash-4.4$ ls -la
total 300
drwx--S---   4 jav  0  24576 Oct 17 14:41 .
drwxrwsrwx 102 qsys 0  61440 Oct 17 15:21 ..
-rw-------   1 jav  0   2108 Oct 17 15:32 .bash_history
-rwx------   1 jav  0    204 Dec 18  2018 .bash_profile
-rwx------   1 jav  0     83 May  5  2017 .bashrc
drwxrwsrwx   3 jav  0   8192 May  9  2018 .eclipse
-rwx------   1 jav  0    559 Oct 17 16:45 .profile
-rw-------   1 jav  0    546 Oct 22  2018 .sh_history
drwx--S---   2 jav  0   8192 Oct 17 16:55 .ssh
bash-4.4$
```

Very very verbose output when trying a failed attempt:

```
┌─[dl @ PC-1802]─[~/.ssh]─[575]
└─[$]› ssh -vvv JAVDL
OpenSSH_7.6p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /c/Users/dl/.ssh/config
debug1: /c/Users/dl/.ssh/config line 55: Applying options for JAVDL
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug2: resolving "mydomain.local" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to mydomain.local [10.0.15.8] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/Users/dl/.ssh/dl_rsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/Users/dl/.ssh/dl_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.6
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_8.0
debug1: match: OpenSSH_8.0 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to mydomain.local:22 as 'jav'
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/c/Users/dl/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /c/Users/dl/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type RSA in file /c/Users/dl/.ssh/known_hosts:4
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 2 keys from mydomain.local
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,aes256-cbc,aes192-cbc
debug2: ciphers stoc: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,aes256-cbc,aes192-cbc
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
debug2: host key algorithms: rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: umac-64-etm@openssh.com compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: umac-64-etm@openssh.com compression: none
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:7Z25Q7mljYwlFOHC0SPGiCraFwbW/Pm4ecbfLL/w29E
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/c/Users/dl/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /c/Users/dl/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type RSA in file /c/Users/dl/.ssh/known_hosts:4
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 2 keys from mydomain.local
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/c/Users/dl/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /c/Users/dl/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from 10.0.15.8
debug1: Host 'mydomain.local' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /c/Users/dl/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks
debug2: key: /c/Users/dl/.ssh/dl_rsa (0x0), explicit
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 7
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521>
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,keyboard-interactive
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,keyboard-interactive
debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/dl/.ssh/dl_rsa


Enter passphrase for key '/c/Users/dl/.ssh/dl_rsa':


debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: RSA SHA256:YVE0kS2H4/n5umGS4Gv0J+aWFljM4pauXG8KEe1+2YI
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,keyboard-interactive
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup keyboard-interactive
debug3: remaining preferred: password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive
debug2: userauth_kbdint
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a keyboard-interactive packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,keyboard-interactive
debug3: userauth_kbdint: disable: no info_req_seen
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
jav@mydomain.local: Permission denied (publickey,keyboard-interactive).

┌─[dl @ PC-1802]─[~/.ssh]─[576]
└─[$]›
```

Permission on `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`:

```
bash-4.4$ pwd
/home/JAV/.ssh
bash-4.4$ ls -la
total 40
drwx--S--- 2 jav 0  8192 Oct 17 17:22 .
drwx--S--- 4 jav 0 24576 Oct 17 14:41 ..
-rwx------ 1 jav 0  1303 Oct 17 16:55 authorized_keys
bash-4.4$
```

SSH host alias definition I'm using:

```
Host JAVDL
  HostName mydomain.local
  Port 22
  User jav
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/dl_rsa
```

I'd also like to note that in our `sshd_config` file we have explicit deny/allow directives.

Portion of `sshd_config`

```
DenyUsers root
AllowUsers dl jav
```

I can't find any indication of what `debug3: receive packet: type 51` means.  Maybe my Googling skills are lacking, but I can't even find a reference to what the various packet types are for openssh, not even in the [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4253).

Comment: Do you have verbose output of the _server-side_ sshd logs? (That's where the check and rejection are happening, after all.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, SSHD logging isn't enabled by default on IBM i.  To set it up, follow this article: https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/sshd-can-use-unix-syslog-facilities-logging

Then, after increasing the logLevel on the server to `DEBUG3` I found the entry:

```
sshd[262719]: User jav not allowed because shell /QOpenSys/QIBM/ProdData/OPS/tools/bin/bash does not exist
```

That file does not exist on our system, but it also shouldn't exist as we installed `bash` from IBM's YUM repository.  That is the location of `bash` if using 5733OPS to obtain bash, which is now considered obsolete.

After some searching I determined there is a UDF which sets the default `PASE` shell for a given user.  `QSYS2.SET_PASE_SHELL_INFO()` as explained here: http://archive.ibmsystemsmag.com/blogs/open-your-i/august-2017/tech-tip-be-like-a-turtle/.  After querying the value for the user "jav" and comparing it to a user for which this works, I found the user "jav" had the value set to `/QOpenSys/QIBM/ProdData/OPS/tools/bin/bash` while the value for all other users was `NULL`.  Sure enough, after setting the value to `NULL`, everything worked as expected.

I gather you can set the default shell using this method instead of using startup files such as `.profile`.  We just use startup files though.

Query to check the value for all users:

```
SELECT AUTHORIZATION_NAME, PASE_SHELL_PATH
FROM QSYS2.USER_INFO;
```

Answer (score 0):

> I can't find any indication of what debug3: receive packet: type 51 means. Maybe my Googling skills are lacking, but I can't even find a reference to what the various packet types are for openssh, not even in the RFC.

Packet 51 means SSH_MSG_USERAUTH_FAILURE as described in the RFC 4252:

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4252#section-6

This means the key was rejected for some reason, which is recorded in the server logs (or will be recorded if you increase logLevel on the server).